# Angular4 AutoComplete running extremely slow, how do I speed it up

Tags: angular, autocomplete, observable

I'm building a form on my website that allows users to search for clients from a database, to do this I'm pre-loading the clients and then setting an angular 4 autocomplete component to use the list of clients, however it runs extremely slow when rendering the dropdown. I've determined this is because there are just so many results to show, often-times 6000+.

Is there a way to have the autocomplete use a custom function I've built that waits till it determines the user is finished typing before returning results, right now I'm using the exact same code shown in angulars examples.

Here is the TS code behind the component:

```
this.filteredCustomers = this.customerControl.valueChanges
            .startWith(null)
            .map(val => val ? this.filterCustomers(val) : null);

filterCustomers(val: string): any {
        return this.agencyCustomers.filter(function (item: any) {
            var n = item.Name.trim().toLowerCase();
            return (n.search(val) >= 0);
        });
    }
```

And here is the html:

```
<md-autocomplete #customers="mdAutocomplete">
                    <md-option *ngFor="let customer of filteredCustomers | async" [value]="customer.Name" [innerText]="customer.Name" (onSelectionChange)="customerChanged(customer, transaction)">
                    </md-option>
                </md-autocomplete>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u pls provide a plnkr ?

Comment: Try use primeng component https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete

Comment: PrimeNG works beautifully and was just what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through several solutions, I've decided to use the primeng components package, as it solved my issue as well as provides many other extremely useful components that Angular's base component set just doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

```
You Can Use Angular2 Auto Complete
--------------------------------------

Here is the link
```

- https://github.com/sksushil999/auto-complete

`And You see example`

- http://plnkr.co/edit/ExzNSh?p=preview

It has many features.This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use virual list in dropdown, for rendering only small chunk.

In example - http://rintoj.github.io/angular2-virtual-scroll/

Answer (score 1):

This drop down i used and version "^1.1.11".I have updated version to 2.0.1 that is little bit faster.But not good because of larger datasets(record) bind inside drop down i think 15k to 20k. That is plugin issue for rendering client side large datasets.

Conclusion:
Need to call API when user write something. and making API as per search parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use Teradata/covalent library

https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/virtual-scroll

```
<mat-form-field flex>
        <mat-label>Test</mat-label>
        <input name="test" matInput [matAutocomplete]="tdAuto"
              [(ngModel)]="testmodel" #test="ngModel" required
              (ngModelChange)="filter(testmodel)">
        <mat-autocomplete #tdAuto="matAutocomplete">
            <td-virtual-scroll-container #virtualScroll 
                         [style.height.px]="200" [data]="data">
                  <ng-template let-row="row" let-last="last" tdVirtualScrollRow>
                      <mat-option [value]="row">
                         <span>{{row}}</span>
                      </mat-option>
                  </ng-template>
            </td-virtual-scroll-container>

       </mat-autocomplete>
       <mat-error *ngIf="test.invalid">Obligated</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```